# ACRA send report without exiting app

Tags: android, acra

Just started using ACRA. When the application crashes it sends a report to my server. All is well.

But there are exceptions which I can catch and let the user keep the problem without error - like using default values. But I'd like to get an error report without bothering the user. But when I do:

```
ErrorReporter errorReporter = ACRA.getErrorReporter();
errorReporter.putCustomData("test", "value");
errorReporter.handleSilentException(null);
```

the application shuts down. I first tried throwing some error (testing purposes), I hoped sending `null` would stop the app from stopping - I was wrong.

Is there a way to use ACRA to send an error report without exiting the app? Just thought I had it, but

```
ErrorReporter errorReporter = ACRA.getErrorReporter();
errorReporter.putCustomData("test", "value");
errorReporter.handleException(null, false); // false is endApplication param, `null` seems to result in a NullPointerException
```

This also closes the application (without an additional Exception from ACRA):

```
ErrorReporter errorReporter = ACRA.getErrorReporter();
errorReporter.putCustomData("test", "value");
errorReporter.handleException(new RuntimeException("message"), false); // tried `true` also, just in case
```

Also closes the app

**Update:**
(1) LogCat shows no stack trace.
(2) While reading the error report, my eye fell on

```
"DUMPSYS_MEMINFO":"Permission Denial: can't dump meminfo from from pid=1416, uid=10048 without permission android.permission.DUMP\n"
```

Tried to add `android.permission.DUMP` to `androidmanifest.xml`, but I get `Permission is only granted to system apps`. Reason for exiting app? Work around? It gets all information that I need (and more)...

Comment: I think you have to put `errorReporter.handleException(t, false); ` in `catch` block, where `t` is the throwable itself.

Comment: @bigdestroyer makes sense.. But to no avail... Btw, if it would crash like that, I'd get a stack trace in logcat - I should have added I don't get a stack trace in logcat

Comment: For the reference, the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/ea3a57384425efa3af589bd0719747e9978fe338/src/main/java/org/acra/ErrorReporter.java#L690). From that `endsApplication = false` should work as you think. How does the app terminate? If it raises an exception, can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: @dhke I get no stack trace... Like my update (which you couldn't have seen) might be informative? (no stack trace in LogCat, but some information in Error Report)

Comment: @dhke I messed up somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the above code is correct. The problem was in that I have overwritten the `ErrorReporter`:

```
new HttpSender(org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT, org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON, null) {
            @Override
            public void send(final Context context, final CrashReportData report) throws ReportSenderException {
                super.send(context, report);
                respondAsIfCrashing(); // not the real method name
            }
        };
```

The application wasn't crashing, it just appeared to do that, because of the `respondAsIfCrashing` method.

The warning `DUMPSYS_MEMINFO":"Permission Denial: can't dump meminfo from from pid=1416, uid=10048 without permission android.permission.DUMP` is, apparently, not a reason to crash... (perhaps just not writing to device?)

So using

```
ErrorReporter errorReporter = ACRA.getErrorReporter();
errorReporter.handleException(new RuntimeException("message"), false);
```

Is sufficient